# What is the probability of picking two black cards out of a pack of ten?

Tags: probability

I have ten cards; eight of them are red, and the remaining two are black.

What is the probability of choosing both black cards in four draws?

I have tried $\frac{3 \cdot 4}{2} \cdot \frac{3 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4}{7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10}$, which gives me the answer $\frac{864}{5040}$, which is approximately equal to $17.14$%, but I do not think my calculations are correct.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What have you tried? Edit your post to include your own attempt at answering this question.

Comment: Are the draws made with or without replacement?

Comment: Without replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be
$$
\dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}=\dfrac{4*7}{210}=\dfrac{2}{15}
$$

I have not considered the order.